# Connectivity of this set: $A=\{x: \operatorname{dist}(x,F)=\epsilon\}?$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness

Suppose $F$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ ($n>1$). How to prove that if $F$ and the complement of $F$ are connected, then so is
$A=\{x: \operatorname{dist}(x,F)=\epsilon\}?$ Suppose $\epsilon>0$.

Intuitively we can say that if $A$ is disconnected and $C$ is one of its components, then there is an open set $V$ that contains $C$ (which is closed) and the boundary $b V$ doesn't intersect $A\setminus C$. So at each point on $b V$ the distance to $F$ must be either $>\epsilon$ or $<\epsilon$ (intermediate value theorem). But at the same time, if you take a point $x\in A$ and $y\in F$ such that $\operatorname{dist}(x,y)=\epsilon$, then the line $L$ through $x$ and $y$ intersects $b V$ at (at least) two points: $z_1$ and $z_2$ and the distance of both from $F$ cannot be neither $<\epsilon$ nor $>\epsilon$. Is this correct? If yes how can we write it down as a proof?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]This is not true.

In $\mathbb{R}^2 \simeq \mathbb{C}$, consider $B = \lbrace z \in \mathbb{C} \text{ }|\text{ } 2\varepsilon \leq z \leq 3\varepsilon \rbrace$, and
$$F = B \setminus \lbrace z \in \mathbb{C} \text{ }|\text{ } \mathrm{Im}(z)<0, |\mathrm{Re}(z)|< \varepsilon/2\rbrace$$

It is easy (just make a picture) to see that $F$ is connected, $\mathbb{C} \setminus F$ is connected, but $A = \lbrace z \in \mathbb{C} \text{ }|\text{ }d(z,F) = \varepsilon \rbrace$ looks like the union of the two circles of radii $\varepsilon$ and $4\varepsilon$, therefore $A$ is not connected.

Comment: Thanks. I think you mean $B=\{z| 2\varepsilon\leq |z|\leq 3\varepsilon\}$ and $F=B\setminus\{z|Im(z)<0, |Re(z)|<\varepsilon/2\}$. Is that correct? If yes, can you explain why $A$ is the union of the two circles of radii $\varepsilon$ and $4\varepsilon$?

Comment: Yes you are right, you can define $F$ like that. I edited, see the picture !

Comment: So $A$ is not two FULL circles, but still disconnected. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @M.Rahmat Yes indeed, $A$ is not *really* two full circles, it has two connected components that look like circles :)