# Connectivity of this set 2: $A=\{x: 0<\operatorname{dist}(x,F)<\epsilon\}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, algebraic-topology, connectedness

Suppose $F$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ ($n>1$) and $\epsilon>0$ is fixed.  If $F$ and the complement of $F$ are connected, can we say that
$A=\{x: 0<\operatorname{dist}(x,F)<\epsilon\}?$ is also connected?

Here is what I did. For $n=1$ suppose we have a set $I$ that is open and disconnected. Then, by setting $a=\inf I$ and $b=\sup I$, we can prove that the set $(-\infty,a]\cup I\cup[b,\infty)$ is disconnected.

I tried to do the same think with the above problem. Let $B$ be the set of points whose distance from $F$ is $\geq \epsilon$. Then the complement of $F$ is $A\cup B$. And I try to prove that if $A$ is disconnected, then the complement of $F$ will be disconnected, and hence contradiction. But I couldn't finish the argument.

Comment: Does the number 2 in the title refer to the fact that you have another question which is a bit related: [Connectivity of this set: $A=\{x: \operatorname{dist}(x,F)=\epsilon\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3914703).

Comment: This sounds correct. Here is a heuristic idea: Since $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus F$ is open and connected, it is path-connected. So, if $x, y \in A$, then we can find a path $\gamma$ joining from $x$ to $y$. Now we should be able to deform this path so that it remains close to $F$, which will then show that $A$ is path-connected.

Comment: @ Sangchul Lee. Thanks. What do you mean by deform a path so that it remains close to $F$? . Do you have a reference for that?