# Is the set of points having the same distance from a closed set connected?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness

This question is related to this ([Connectivity of this set: $A=\{x: \operatorname{dist}(x,F)=\epsilon\}?$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3914703/connectivity-of-this-set-a-x-operatornamedistx-f-epsilon)). Suppose $F$ is a closed set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n>1$. Suppose $F$ and its complement are connected. The counterexample given in the previous post prove that for a given $\epsilon>0$ we can not say that the set
$$A_\epsilon=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n: \text{dist}(x,F)=\epsilon\}$$ is connected. How about the following question: For every $\delta>0$, there exists $0<\epsilon<\delta$ such that $A_\epsilon$ is connected? Notice that the counterexample given in the previous post does not  give a negative answer to this question.

Comment: Your question is not bad, but the title is fairly meaningless. Try to improve it.

Comment: Hint: use an infinite union of scaled versions of the example from the linked post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the counterexample from the previous post. Now place similar "cut annuli" one next to the other connected with a strip. Have the length of the "cut" be a sequence that goes to 0. I haven't carefully proved it, but it seems that the complement of this set is open, so it is closed. Both the set and its complement are connected, but for all sufficiently small $ \epsilon > 0 $ there will be a component of $ A_\epsilon $ trapped inside one of the "cut annuli" (actually there will be infinitely many such components).

[image: shape in question]

Comment: It seems to me that this way if you connect the "cuts" to have a connected set, then the complement becomes disconnected. If you make a sequence of these sets, each has a cut made by one term of the sequence and take the union, again the complement seems disconnected. Am I wrong?

Comment: I have uploaded a picture of the set I had in mind, I think that the connectedness of both the set and its complement are obvious.

Comment: Great solution!  You can also get a region bounded by a rectifiable Jordan curve, like a crab with infinitely many claws, getting smaller and smaller.